# opencv java modify pixel values

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I've been trying to convert some opencv C++ code in opencv java and I can't seem to get pixel division to work properly. I take a meanshiftsegmented mat that I convert to grayscale then to 32F.

I then compare the most downsampled then upsampled image (which is comprised of the gray meanshift mat) to the original gray meanshift mat.

I've already read [Using get() and put() to access pixel values in OpenCV for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035005/using-get-and-put-to-access-pixel-values-in-opencv-for-java)

however, it and others like it do not work. The error message I am getting is invalid mat type 5. However, even if I were able to see the saliency map I am positive it is wrong. This is because when I pass in image 001.jpg in c++ I am supposed to see the original image + red square around the objects. In java, I am only seeing the original image at the end.

NOTE :

AbstractImageProvider.deepCopy(AbstractImageProvider.matToBufferedImage(Saliency),disp);

Is an API call that works when I attempt to show the original mat, meanShift mat, and the gray meanShift mat. It fails at showing saliency.

c++

I only did a channel split because I was testing out other colorspaces, however in java I only want to use grayscale.

```
  input = MeanShift.clone();
  input.convertTo(input, CV_32F);

  for(int i = 0; i < Pyramid_Size; i++){DS_Pyramid[i] = input.clone();}

  for (int i = 0; i < Pyramid_Size; i++){ 
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++){ // Why don't I just downsamplex3 a copy of MeanShift.clone then upsamplex3 that same one? ...
      pyrDown (DS_Pyramid[i], DS_Pyramid[i], Size(DS_Pyramid[i].cols/2, DS_Pyramid[i].rows/2));
      US_Pyramid[i] = DS_Pyramid[i].clone();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
      pyrUp (US_Pyramid[i], US_Pyramid[i], Size(US_Pyramid[i].cols*2, US_Pyramid[i].rows*2));
    }
  }

  top = US_Pyramid[Pyramid_Size - 1].clone(); // most down sampled layer, up sampled.
  split(top, top_chs);
  split(input.clone(), meanShift_chs); // split into channels result
  split(input.clone(), sal_chs); // holder to use for compare

  float top_min = 1.0;
  float ms_min = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < top.rows; i++){   // find the smallest value in both top and meanShift
    for (int k = 0; k < top.cols; k++){ // this is so you can sub out the 0 with the min value
      for (int j = 0; j < top.channels(); j++){ // later on
    float a = top_chs[j].at<float>(i,k);
    float b = meanShift_chs[j].at<float>(i,k);
    if (a < top_min && a >= 0) {top_min = a;} // make sure you don't have a top_min of zero... that'd be bad.
    if (b < ms_min && b >= 0)  { ms_min = b;}
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < top.rows; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < top.cols; k++){
      for (int j = 0; j < top.channels(); j++){
    float a,b,c;
    a = top_chs[j].at<float>(i,k);
    b = meanShift_chs[j].at<float>(i,k);

    if (a <= 0){a = top_min;} // make sure you don't divide by zero
    if (b <= 0){b = ms_min;} // make sure you really don't divide by zero
    if (a <= b){c = 1.0 - a/b;}
    else {c = 1.0 - b/a;}

    // c = sqrt(c); // makes stuff more salient, but makes noise pop out too
    sal_chs[j].at<float>(i,k) = c;
      }
    }
  }
  merge(sal_chs, Saliency); // combine into saliency map
  imshow("saliency", Saliency);
```

java

```
    MeanShift = inputImage.clone();

    Imgproc.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(MeanShift, MeanShift, MeanShift_spatialRad, MeanShift_colorRad);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(MeanShift, MeanShift, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    MeanShift.convertTo(MeanShift, CvType.CV_32F);                 // 32F between 0 - 1. ************** IMPORTANT LINE

    for (int i = 0; i < PyrSize; i++){
        DS_Pyramid.add(new Mat());
        UP_Pyramid.add(new Mat());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PyrSize; i++){    
        DS_Pyramid.set(i, MeanShift);
    }       

    for (int i = 0; i < PyrSize; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++){                               // At 0 is downsampled once, second twice, third 3 times. 
        Imgproc.pyrDown(DS_Pyramid.get(i), DS_Pyramid.get(i)); // pyrDown by default img.width / 2 img height / 2
        Mat a = new Mat();                                     // save the sampled down at i
        a = DS_Pyramid.get(i);                            
        UP_Pyramid.add(a);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        Imgproc.pyrUp(UP_Pyramid.get(i),UP_Pyramid.get(i));    
        }                                                          
    }
    top = UP_Pyramid.get(PyrSize-1);
    bot = MeanShift.clone();
    Saliency = MeanShift.clone();


    //http://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/
    //http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/applying_weighted_average_filter.htm

    for (int i = 0; i < top.rows(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < top.cols(); j++){
        int index = i * top.rows() + j;

        float[] top_temp = top.get(i, j);
        float[] bot_temp  = bot.get(i,j);
        float[] sal_temp = bot.get(i,j);

        if (top_temp[0] <= bot_temp[k]){sal_temp[0] = 1.0f - (top_temp[0]/bot_temp[0]);}
        else                           {sal_temp[0] = 1.0f - (bot_temp[0]/top_temp[0]);}

        Saliency.put(i,j, sal_temp);
        }
    }

    AbstractImageProvider.deepCopy(AbstractImageProvider.matToBufferedImage(Saliency),disp);
```

Comment: What is 'k' meant to be in the Java code line starting if (top_temp[k] <= bot_temp[k]){sal_temp[k] ?

Comment: Ahh, my mistake I meant for it to be 0. Thanks for pointing that out!
I also got most of the java code to work now...but for whatever reason the blobs I'm getting in java are small than that of c++ 

The correct result as shown in c++
http://i.imgur.com/5PsJxPi.png

The incorrect result as shown in java
http://i.imgur.com/fPnZPOu.png

Answer (score 6):

Found a simple and working solution after a lot of searching. This might help you get past the error- **invalid mat type 5**

**Code:**

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread("Input.jpg"); //Reads image from the file system and puts into matrix
int rows = img.rows(); //Calculates number of rows
int cols = img.cols(); //Calculates number of columns
int ch = img.channels(); //Calculates number of channels (Grayscale: 1, RGB: 3, etc.)

for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)
    {
        double[] data = img.get(i, j); //Stores element in an array
        for (int k = 0; k < ch; k++) //Runs for the available number of channels
        {
            data[k] = data[k] * 2; //Pixel modification done here
        }
        img.put(i, j, data); //Puts element back into matrix
    }
}
Highgui.imwrite("Output.jpg", img); //Writes image back to the file system using values of the modified matrix
```

**Note:** An important point that has not been mentioned anywhere online is that the method `put` does not write pixels onto `Input.jpg`. It merely updates the values of the matrix `img`. Therefore, the above code does not alter anything in the input image. For producing a visible output, the matrix `img` needs to be written onto a file i.e., `Output.jpg` in this case. Also, using `img.get(i, j)` seems to be a better way of handling the matrix elements rather than using the accepted solution above as this helps in visualizing and working with the image matrix in a better way and does not require a large contiguous memory allocation.