# Finding Percentage of color in image OpenCV Android SDK

Tags: java, android, opencv, colors

I'm working on an Android Project for Color Detection using OpenCV Android SDK. I have been able to separate the green and brown mask from the image but i want the percent of green and brown color in the image. I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

```
oImage = imread(pathOfFile);
hsvImage = new Mat();
color_range1 = new Mat();
color_range2 = new Mat();

Imgproc.cvtColor(oImage, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(25,52,72), new Scalar(102,255,255), color_range1); // Green
Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(10, 100, 20), new Scalar(20, 255, 200), color_range2); // Brown

// I have the Green and Brown mask in color_range1 and color_range2 respectively.
// Now what

color_range1.release();
color_range2.release();
hsvImage.release();
oImage.release();
```

I have a working Python implementation of the solution but not sure how to convert it to Java.

```
    img = cv2.imread("__FILE_PATH__")
    grid_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_green = np.array([25,52,72])
    upper_green = np.array([102,255,255])

    lower_brown = np.array([10, 100, 20])
    upper_brown = np.array([20, 255, 200])

    mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_green, upper_green)
    brown_mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_brown, upper_brown)

    Green Percent - round(((mask>0).mean())*100,3)
    Brown Percent - round(((brown_mask>0).mean())*100,3)
```

Comment: My answer before was correct, it doest matter rgb or hsv, reaching pixel is same way.

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk can you post it here. I deleted that question to post it again.

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk and then how can I get the percentage of green and brown color?

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk can you post it again please. I deleted the previous question. And does the result match with the python implementation above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read every pixel of your image by one by as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056910/opencv-java-modify-pixel-values) and then count them.

```
    int color_range1_counter = 0;
    int color_range2_counter = 0;


    for (int i=0; i<hsvImage.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<hsvImage.cols; j++)
        {
            double[] hsv = image.get(0, 0);
            if(hsv[0]>25 && hsv[0]<102 && hsv[1]>52 && hsv[1]<255 && hsv[2]>72 && hsv[2]<255)
            color_range1_counter++;

            if(hsv[0]>10 && hsv[0]<20 && hsv[1]>100 && hsv[1]<255 && hsv[2]>20 && hsv[2]<200)
            color_range2_counter++;

        }
    }
    double percentage = color_range1_counter/(color_range1_counter + color_range2_counter)
```

**Note:** *The channel(pixel) values are determined according to your inRange scalar limits.*

Comment: does your solution give the percentage of color in the image or the mask???

Comment: Yes,  it should give the pixel number of green and brown. Just divide them to total

Comment: total pixels of image or total of green and brown mask.

Comment: Yes, i assumed your image only consist brown and green. Thats why i did like that.  You should divide to total