# Modify Mat object Pixel values by using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, mat

I'm a beginner in Android Programming.I'm building an Android App for Image Steganography.I already developed this application for Desktop using Java and OpenCV,which works Perfectly.I'm trying to re-use the code,which I have.

I created a `Mat` Object and passed it to the Java Class(which I already have).I'm able to read the Pixel Intensities in the `Mat` Object,But,when I'm trying to modify those values (by using `put()`),my app is getting crashed.

The Exception thrown was

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hari.imagesteganography, PID: 8850
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Provided data element number (3) should be multiple of the Mat channels count (4)
        at org.opencv.core.Mat.put(Mat.java:954)
        at com.example.hari.imagesteganography.LSBImageStego.encodeOriginalMessageBinaryLength(LSBImageStego.java:101)
        at com.example.hari.imagesteganography.LSBImageStego.encodeImage(LSBImageStego.java:239)
        at com.example.hari.imagesteganography.EncodeActivity$1.onClick(EncodeActivity.java:98)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6302)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24782)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The same method (`put()`) works perfectly fine running on Desktop.

Following is my Code in the Android application.

```
private void encodeOriginalMessageBinaryLength(){

// LOGGING THIS,SHOWS THAT THE FUNCTION EXECUTION STARTED
        Log.i("URI" , "encodeOriginalMessageBinaryLength()");

        String binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength = Integer.toBinaryString(this.originalMessageBinaryLength);
        if(binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength.length()%2 !=0){
            binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength = "0" + binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength;
        }
        int remaining = binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength.length();
        String newLsbBits;

        for(int col = this.coverImage_cols -1 ; col >=0 ; col--){
            if(remaining > 0){
                newLsbBits = binary_of_originalMessageBinaryLength.substring( remaining - NUMBER_OF_BITS_REPLACING , remaining );
                remaining -= NUMBER_OF_BITS_REPLACING;

            }else{
                newLsbBits = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(NUMBER_OF_BITS_REPLACING, "0"));
            }

            Log.i("URI","newLsbBits"+newLsbBits);
            String modifiedBinaryString = this.getBeautifiedBinaryString(this.coverImage.get( this.coverImage_rows -1,col )[0]).substring(0 , this.getBeautifiedBinaryString(this.coverImage.get( this.coverImage_rows -1,col )[0]).length() - NUMBER_OF_BITS_REPLACING) + newLsbBits;

            Log.i("URI","modifiedBianryString"+modifiedBinaryString);
            double[] data = new double[3];
            data[0] = Integer.parseInt(modifiedBinaryString , 2);
            data[1] = this.coverImage.get( this.coverImage_rows -1,col )[1];
            data[2] = this.coverImage.get( this.coverImage_rows -1,col )[2];
this.coverImage_rows -1,col )[0]);

//   LOGGING THE DIMENSIONS OF THE IMAGE CORRECTLY,SHOWS THAT THE Mat Object 
//   IS INITIALIZED CORRECTLY
            Log.i("URI" , new Integer(this.coverImage_rows).toString());
            Log.i("URI" , new Integer(this.coverImage_cols).toString());

//  EXECUTING BELOW LINE CAUSES THE APP TO CRASH
            this.coverImage.put( this.coverImage_rows -1,col  , data);


// BELOW MESSAGE IS NOT BEING LOGGED
           Log.i("URI" , "encodeOriginalMessageBinaryLength() END");

        }
}
```

The Corresponding Logcat log is as follows.

```
2019-02-08 12:30:37.019 1230-1230/com.example.hari.imagesteganography I/URI: encodeOriginalMessageBinaryLength()
2019-02-08 12:30:37.019 1230-1230/com.example.hari.imagesteganography I/URI: newLsbBits10
2019-02-08 12:30:37.019 1230-1230/com.example.hari.imagesteganography I/URI: modifiedBianryString10010110
2019-02-08 12:30:37.019 1230-1230/com.example.hari.imagesteganography I/URI: 1440
2019-02-08 12:30:37.019 1230-1230/com.example.hari.imagesteganography I/URI: 2560
```

The `Mat` Object and other attributes are being set as follows

```
public LSBImageStego(Mat coverImage){
        this.coverImage = coverImage;
        this.coverImage_rows = (int)coverImage.size().height;
        this.coverImage_cols = (int)coverImage.size().width;
}
```

Is my code wrong?How to change Pixel Intensity values of `Mat` Object using OpenCV and Java in Android?

I believe that,this question is not duplicate of [Using get() and put() to access pixel values in OpenCV for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035005/using-get-and-put-to-access-pixel-values-in-opencv-for-java)
OR
[opencv java modify pixel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056910/opencv-java-modify-pixel-values)
,as they are not intended for Android, and the `put()` method described in those questions,works fine even for me on Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Method `put()` is overloaded in Mat class.
For each Mat type a specific data type is required. 
For example, if you Mat type is `CV_32S` the data required is int [].
You can check the implementation of Mat class for all Mat types.